# What is the meaning of argv[1][0]?

Tags: c

I am reading codes of `mcachefs` and could not understand some codes, like below:

```
printf("mcachefs " __MCACHEFS_VERSION__ " starting up...\n");

if (argc == 1 || argv[1][0] == '-')
{
    fprintf(stderr,
        "\tError : first argument shall be the the mcachefs_mountpoint !\n");
    exit(2);
}
```

I have two questions:
1: For `printf("mcachefs " __MCACHEFS_VERSION__ " starting up...\n")`, is it the correct way to use `printf`? I have never seen such way of using it.

1. What is the meaning of `argv[1][0]`? I know `argv[]` represents the arguments from the command line. But, is not it a **one dimension** array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When the C compiler sees a lot of string literals next to each other, it concatenates them into one long string. So that use of `printf()` is OK, as long as the macro `__MCACHEFS_VERSION__` expands to a string. That string had better not contain any percent characters... I'd write it as

   `printf("mcachefs %s starting up...\n", __MCACHEFS_VERSION__);`
2. As others have pointed out, `argv[1]` is the second string in the string array `argv`, and strings are character arrays so `argv[1][0]` is the first character in the second string.

Comment: I think the original method is better, since the compiler will complain if something weird is placed in the macro. With this method, you might print garbage/crash program if someone modify the macro.

Comment: he should still use puts rather than printf

Comment: @nhahtdh you can print garbage or crash the program the original way if the modification works out.

Comment: @GrahamLee: Can you give an example?

Comment: @nhahtdh #define __MCACHEFS_VERSION__ "%n%n%n%n%n%n%n%n" crashes for me.

Comment: @nhahtdh and the compiler complains if I define the macro to be the wrong type when I do it my way: Untitled.c:6:20: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
        printf("mcachefs %s starting up...\n", __MCACHEFS_VERSION__);
                         ~^                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                         %d

Comment: @GrahamLee: String literal way suffers from format string, as you have pointed out (not sure if there is any other case), but it is also detectable by the compiler with `-Wformat` flag. Another thing is that only string literal can be inserted that way. If format string is the only weakness, then the compiler can detects the error, if any. On the other hand, supplying as argument allows for more things to be passed in. And it is possible to circumvent all warning mechanism, by doing an explicit cast.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, it is very likely that `__MCACHEFS_VERSION__` is macro for a string literal. In C, string literals are concatenated if there is nothing between them.

For the second question, `argv[1][0]` refers to the first character of the first argument passed into the function (e.g. if you type a command `myprogram -la` then `myprogram` can be accessed from argv[0], and `-la` will be in `argv[1]`). `argv[0]` is the name of the executable, so the arguments to the executable will be from index 1.

The code therefore checks whether `argc == 1`, which means no argument passed in, or `argv[1][0] == '-'`, which means the first argument is something like a flag, and return error. The logic here is: we check for the number of arguments first, and if the number of arguments is not 1 (short circuit effect of logical operator), then we check for the first argument.

Answer (score 1):

It means the first character of the second string of `argv`.

Answer (score 1):

This would determine if the first character of the first parameter is a dash.

So for

```
command -firstparam
```

(argc == 1 || argv[1][0] == '-') would evaluate to true.

Answer (score 1):

`argv[1][0]` refers to the 1st character of the 2nd string.

The expression

`if (argc == 1 || argv[1][0])`

relies on the languages short circuit evaluation to safe-gaurd the array dereference.In other words if the the test `argc == 1` fails then the subsequent expression `argv[1][0]` is not evalauted. If it was then the derefence may cause a segfault.

The expression in the printf relies on C languages support for the concatenation of string literals. The macro `__MCACHEFS_VERSION__` will be #defined as as string literal somewhere. It allows you to split strings across new lines, or use them in macros as shown in your example. See here for more examples of string literal concatenation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#String_literal_concatenation

Answer (score 1):

1. `__MCACHEFS_VERSION__` is a macro for a string literal, e.g. `"1.0"`. When multiple string literals are placed adjacently they are concatenated: `"Version:" __MCACHEFS_VERSION__ "..."` would become `"Version: 1.0..."` in this case.
2. `argv[1][0]` refers to the first element of second element. It is equivalent to:

   `const char* firstArg = argv[1];`

   `char firstCharOfFirstArg = firstArg[0];`

Answer (score 1):

argv is a one-dimensional array. It's elements are character pointers. So argv[i] gives a pointer to a char in memory. The values in argv point to the first character of the program name (as a c null terminated "string") and any additional arguments passed to the program.

argv[0] ------->  my_program
argv[1] ------->  -some_arg

To get the character that is pointed to by an argv element you can use the dereference operator:

*argv[1]

or, C also allows array syntax to dereference a pointer:
argv[1][0] /* dereference the pointer stored in argv[1] */

It may be clearer if the character pointer is used outside the argv array:

```
char *arg1 = argv[1]

printf("first char of the first arg is %c\n",*arg1);  /* dereference char pointer */
printf("another way to access first char of %c\n",arg1[0]); /* dereference char pointer */
```